# loading modules from iPython from a random directory in windows 7

Tags: python, import, module, ipython

From iPython:
I can load a module from a sub-directory (i.e. c:\users\userX\myPythonFoo\bar.py)
I can run bar.myStuff()
First line of code is:

from myPythonFoo import bar

I would like to move the directory C:\users\userX\myPythonFoo to Z:\PythonStuff\myPythonFoo

Is there an easy way to do this without modifying iPython?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before starting IPython:

```
set PYTHONPATH=Z:\PythonStuff\myPythonFoo
```

Or if PYTHONPATH is already defined:

```
set PYTHONPATH=Z:\PythonStuff\myPythonFoo;%PYTHONPATH%
```

Not sure what you mean by "modifying IPython" but you can also manually edit `sys.path` from the IPython prompt.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. What I meant, or what I was looking for was a way to not modify the environmental variables. Seems the ":" is the problem and I can't figure out how to get around that.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean about ":", also what you mean by not modifying ipython. What are have you actually tried?